# What is required to get the bootstrap toggle working

Tags: bootstrap-4

I cannot get the bootstrap-toggle effect to work. I have stripped my page down to what I think its the bare minimum requirement:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div>
<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

But my check box just appears like a standard checkbox. What am I missing?

Comment: Sometimes deleting the cache helps with problems such as these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this. Seems like you haven't added jquery and if you have added it please make to to move it to first place.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div>
<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle">
</div>

</body>
```